# In mongoose, how to filter searching results based on the current result?

Tags: database, mongoose, e-commerce, mern

I am getting stuck on my MERN application. I want the user to filter the results of the product. The more criteria the user applies, the narrower the results should be. Eg, if I apply the filter boy, there are 10 results. Then I am trying to apply pants, there should be the only 5 results which matches what I am looking for. But now it doesn't work. Here is the code,

```
exports.getProductsSearchResult = (req, res, next) => {
    let query = {};
    const productCategory = req.query.category;
    const productSize = req.query.size;
    const productGender = req.query.gender
    if (productCategory !== undefined) query.category = productCategory;
    if (productGender !== undefined) query.gender = productGender;
    if (productSize !== undefined) query.size = productSize;
    console.log('query', query)
    Products.find(query).then(product => {
        // console.log(product)
        res.status(200).json(product)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: How is the output for `console.log('query', query)`? Also explain what is "it doesn't work". Where/what is the problem?

Comment: query { category: ’pants’, gender: ’boy’, size: ’1T’} if I apply three params, that is the outcome.

Comment: Can you share a document example, please?

Answer (score 0):

After googling StackOverflow, I find a similar question and solve my problem. Here is the code, right now, I didn't see any bug. But please let me know if there is anything that can be improved.

```
exports.getProductsSearchResult = (req, res, next) => {
    let query = {};
    const productCategory = req.query.category;
    const productSize = req.query.size;
    const productGender = req.query.gender
    let payload = { "category": productCategory, "size": productSize, "gender": productGender }
    if (payload.category && payload.category.length > 0) query.category = { $in: payload.category }
    if (payload.size && payload.size.length > 0) query.size = { $in: payload.size };
    if (payload.gender && payload.gender.length > 0) query.gender = { $in: payload.gender };
    console.log('query', query)
    Products.find(query).then(product => {
        // console.log(product)
        res.status(201).json(product)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```